# HttpContext.Session.SetString() not work in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i add a string in session with using

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("CaptchaCode", result.CaptchaCode);
```

but return null when i want to get value by:

```
context.Session.GetString("CaptchaCode");
```

what is the solution in .net core 3.1?

and this is my Startup.cs ConfigureServices and Configure:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
                {
                    builder.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        if (error != null)
                        {
                            context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            FileExtensionContentTypeProvider contentTypes = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseResponseCompression();
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints();

        }
```

and this is my ConfigureService:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<>(options => options
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("")));
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => { options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; });
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
            services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
                });
            services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
                {
                    options.EnableForHttps = true;
                    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
                });
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            // Add the processing server as IHostedService
            services.AddHttpClient();

            //services
            services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEventService, EventService>();
            services.AddScoped<IFileUploadService, FileUploadService>();
            services.AddScoped<IOrganizerService, OrganizerService>();
            services.AddScoped<IPanelService, PanelService>();
            services.AddScoped<IHomeService, HomeService>();

            //repository
            services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IEventRepository, EventRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IOrganizerRepository, OrganizerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IPanelRepository, PanelRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IHomeRepository, HomeRepository>();

        }
```

i completly configure the session but until doesnt work for me.
I emphasize that i work in .net core 3.1

Comment: have you created a session in the startup file?

Comment: yes,i do it completely

Comment: have you put a break point on the `string foo = context.Session.GetString("CaptchaCode");`

Comment: Yes I put and return null

Comment: Hi @Alireza,Please be sure  `result.CaptchaCode` have value.And how did you get the context in `context.Session.GetString("CaptchaCode");`.I suggest you could share how did you get `result.CaptchaCode` and how did you get context and what is your Startup.cs.

Comment: Hi, @rena 2 tank you for commenting, I'm sure about my result.CaptchaCode has value and I get httpContext in controller and pass to here but I don't know my Startup.cs is OK or not???

Comment: Hi @Alireza,check my working demo. I suggest that you could share your Startup.cs.

Comment: i add my startup.cs configure function to post.@Rena

Comment: Hi @Alireza,What is your ConfigureServices?I could not reproduce your issue any way.How did you register and dependency injection your context?Did you try to use my code to inject IHttpContextAccessor?

Comment: dear @Rena i add ConfigureServices to the post

Comment: Where have you added `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>()`; ?